# Microsoft Graph tutorial errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, target-framework

I'm having an issue with the microsoft graph tutorial, and I'm not sure what to do as I'm new to the C# language. The link to the tutorial is posted below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core?tutorial-step=1

I've followed the tutorial word for word, and when I run the program I'm receiving errors on target frameworks. Wondering if anyone can give insight on this error.

Below are the following errors.

> Extensions\src\DiagnosticAdapter\src\Internal\ProxyAssembly.cs(62,8):
>   error CS1029: #error: 'Target frameworks should be updated'
>   [C:\Users\justinguerrero\Documents\GraphTutorial\GraphTutorial.csproj]
>   Extensions\src\DiagnosticAdapter\src\Internal\ProxyFactory.cs(31,8):
>   error CS1029: #error: 'Target frameworks should be updated'
>   [C:\Users\justinguerrero\Documents\GraphTutorial\GraphTutorial.csproj]
>   Extensions\src\DiagnosticAdapter\src\Internal\ProxyMethodEmitter.cs(237,8):
>   error CS1029: #error: 'Target frameworks should be updated'
>   [C:\Users\justinguerrero\Documents\GraphTutorial\GraphTutorial.csproj]
>   Extensions\src\DiagnosticAdapter\src\Internal\ProxyTypeEmitter.cs(505,8):
>   error CS1029: #error: 'Target frameworks should be updated'
>   [C:\Users\justinguerrero\Documents\GraphTutorial\GraphTutorial.csproj]
>   Extensions\src\DiagnosticAdapter\src\ProxyDiagnosticSourceMethodAdapter.cs(23,8):
>   error CS1029: #error: 'Target frameworks should be updated'
>   [C:\Users\justinguerrero\Documents\GraphTutorial\GraphTutorial.csproj]
>   Extensions\src\TestingUtils\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Testing\src\xunit\FrameworkSkipConditionAttribute.cs(52,8):
>   error CS1029: #error: 'Target frameworks need to be updated.'
>   [C:\Users\justinguerrero\Documents\GraphTutorial\GraphTutorial.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

I've done some googling around but haven't found much, and the github page they've recommended hasn't helped me diagnose this error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

J

Comment: You may need to update the SDK. 
Example for .NET Core. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151040/how-to-update-target-framework-of-net-project
Find out what you project uses and try updating it or if is not the correct framework. Select the correct framework for your project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019

Comment: please add target framework version in the question. you can find it in *.csproj file.

Comment: the tutorial you are following is for .net core so the entry in your project file should be    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

Comment: I following the link the steps in the link you provided. There is no error for me. According to your error, you need to install .net core 3.0.

Comment: Thanks all I will do what I can to get this running. I installed .netcore 3.0 and I'm still getting the error. when i run dotnet --version it says that I'm running 3.0.100